# TTimer in delphi cause wrong thread exception when create a instance form in Android

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

my problem is i have a timer to display a form in time. In iOS it work well with my code, but in android it's display an exception : `android.view.viewrootimpl$calledfromwrongthreadexception only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views`. But i thought timer on delphi will be run under main thread? I also put a `TThread.Synchronize` to check but it's still the same exception. Any idea how to handle this. Thanks.

Here is my code. I start application with Form1, have the timer inside it:

```
timer := TTimer.create(nil);
timer.Interval := time
timer.OnTimer := DoScreenTimerEvent;
```

In DoScreenTimerEvent function in Form1 will show the Form2( this is a screensaver in my application):

```
Form2:= TForm2.create(nil);
Form2.Show;// raised exception here.
```

The problem is i have many form like Form3, Form4, etc... the Form2 will display after interval i had putted in the timer, whenever i'm in Form3, or 4... In iOS, it work perfectly but in android i got above exception.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception indicates, you can't modify views outside the UI thread. If you are on a background thread and need to work on a view, do this:

```
mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can do

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i do think so, tried but it not work. BTW i'm in delphi, not java xD

Comment: @thanh please edit your question to show the actual code you are having trouble with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau sr, i got trouble with my computer past 2 days, i have updated the code, also i make it simpler than my current working with. Thanks

Comment: @thanh Android's [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) class runs in a worker thread. I would have to check if that is what FMX's `TTimer` uses internally, but I suspect it probably does. You said you tried using `TThread.Synchronize()` without success, but you have not shown that code yet.

Comment: @thanh: I looked and `TTimer` is actually using Linux's [`timer_create()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) function to create a timer with a callback function that is called in a worker thread, and that callback is using `TThread.Queue()` to fire the `TTimer.OnTimer` event handler in the main UI thread. So you shouldn't be getting a "wrong thread" error since your `Form2` object would be being created and shown in the main UI thread.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your support, I have created a new project with timer and it works ok with andoird, zzz i'll find what wrongs in my current project( it's large) and have a feedback later. Thanks

Comment: @thanh do you have any update in this subject,i got same error ,i must use `Synchronize` in timer for update ui elements ?! when the timer ontimer event is empty there is no problem but when i put some code for update ui elements it crashed..